# Deploying to Heroku - vapor heroku init command - error

Tags: heroku, vapor, deploying

While trying to deploy to Heruko, I keep getting the question "Would you like to deploy to other than US region server?". If I select n, it displays an error. Not sure why am getting different questions than the tutorial I am following.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was fixed here https://github.com/vapor/toolbox/pull/145

Update your Toolbox installation and try again.

```
brew update toolbox
// or
vapor self update
```